# Modal de React-Bootstrap no se muestra cuando un estado de Mobx-React cambia

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Basicamente tengo un Modal de React-bootstrap que deberia aparecer (mediante un booleano) cuando un estado de React-Mobx cambia, que es mutado cuando se produce un error en un interceptor de Axios. Pero no funciona como se espera, solo empieza a funcionar si refresco la pagina, no antes.

Aqui hay una porcion de codigo del Modal de React-Bootstrap que utiliza Mobx para manejar el prop "show"

```
...
const AppLayout = () => {

  const { errorHandlingStore } = useRootStore();

  ...

  return (
    <>
      <CustomModal
        show={errorHandlingStore.showAlert.isShow}
        onHide={() => {errorHandlingStore.setAlertClose()}}
        message={errorHandlingStore.showAlert.alertMsg}
        type="error"
      />
      ...
    </>
  )
}

export default observer(AppLayout);
```

Este es el codigo del "errorHandlingStore"

```
import { action, computed, makeObservable, observable} from 'mobx';

export class ErrorHandlingStore {
  rootStore;
  showAlert = {
    isShow: false,
    alertMsg: null
  };

  constructor(rootStore) {
    this.rootStore = rootStore;
    makeObservable(this, {
      showAlert: observable,
      getIsShow: computed,
      setAlertData: action,
      setAlertClose: action,
    });
  }

  setAlertData(alertData) {
    this.showAlert = {
      isShow: alertData.isShow,
      alertMsg: alertData.alertMsg
    };
  }

  setAlertClose() {
    this.showAlert.isShow = false;
    this.showAlert.alertMsg = "";
  }

  get getIsShow() {
    return this.showAlert.isShow;
  }

}
```

Este es el componente donde cambie el estado de Mobx y debe gatillar el mostrado del Modal.

```
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import { useRootStore } from 'stores';
import { observer } from 'mobx-react-lite';
import axiosInstance from 'services/axiosInstance';
import { deleteUser } from 'services/auth';

const AxiosResponseInterceptor = () => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const { errorHandlingStore } = useRootStore();

  axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => response, 
    (error) => {
      if(error.response && error.response.status === 401) {
        deleteUser(); // remove user from localstorage
        if(window.location.pathname !== "/login")
          window.location.href = "/login"
      }
      else if(error.response && error.response.data && error.response.data.errorCode) {
        // if has response show the error
        console.log("ENTRO")
        errorHandlingStore.setAlertData({
          isShow: true,
          alertMsg: t(`api_error_${error.response.data.errorCode}`)
        })
      }
      else{
        throw error;
      }
    }
  );

  return null;
}

export default observer(AxiosResponseInterceptor);
```

Y finalmente, este es el componente Modal que estoy utilizando (tener en cuenta que utilizo este mismo componente en otros lugares de la aplicacion sin Mobx [solo con states de React] y funciona bien)

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';
import { StyledModalHeader, StyledModalBody, StyledModalFooter } from './Modal.styled';

const CustomModal = ({
  show,
  onHide,
  size = 'md',
  header = null,
  message,
  footer = null,
  type
}) => {
  return (
    <Modal 
      show={show} 
      onHide={onHide} 
      size={size}
      header={header}
    >
      {(header !== null) && (<StyledModalHeader closeButton>
        {header}
      </StyledModalHeader>)}
      <StyledModalBody type={type}>
        {message} 
      </StyledModalBody>
      {(footer !== null) && <StyledModalFooter>
        {footer}
      </StyledModalFooter>}
    </Modal>
  )
}
```